# Need help in changing the iframe command to anything else in the below code

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.boxy').hide();
    $("#drop1, #drop2").on("change", function () {
        $('.boxy').hide();
        if ($('#drop1').val() !== "" && $('#drop2').val() !== "") {  //code indentation
            $("#content").show();
            $("#content").attr("src", "http://analytics.sial.com/rtp/inventory_analysis.asp?screen=Pricing_Inventory_" + $('#drop2').val());
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="drop1">
    <option value="">Dropdown 1</option>
    <option value="IN">India</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
</select>

<select id="drop2">
    <option value="">Dropdown 2</option>
    <option value="OB">OB</option>
    <option value="AC">AC</option>
    <option value="LQ">LQ</option>
</select>

<iframe id="content" class="boxy" src="about:blank" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

I want to open the result page in the same page while the options are selected... Can the iframe be changed to something else....
Please note, each option has a page content..

Can a `<form>` tag be used.. ?

Comment: Are you loading external page?

Comment: yes.. the page loads only in corp network

Answer (score 0):

**Option1**

Use a php file to get the content and then display. 
eg. say your php file is `content.php` with this line of code:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); ?>
```

and then change your script to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.boxy').hide();
    $("#drop1, #drop2").on("change", function(){
        $('.boxy').hide();
        if ($('#drop1').val() !== "" && $('#drop2').val() !== "") {
            $("#content").show();
         var url = "http://analytics.sial.com/rtp/inventory_analysis.asp?screen=Pricing_Inventory_"+$('#drop2').val();
        $("#content").load('content.php?url='+ url);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Remove the `iframe` and create a `div` like

```
<div id="content" class="boxy"></div>
```

**Option2**

Simply try loading the url to an object tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.boxy').hide();
    $("#drop1, #drop2").on("change", function(){
        $('.boxy').hide();
        if ($('#drop1').val() !== "" && $('#drop2').val() !== "") {
            $("#content").show();             
        $("#content").html('<object data="http://analytics.sial.com/rtp/inventory_analysis.asp?screen=Pricing_Inventory_"+$("#drop2").val()');
        }
    });
});
</script>
<div id="content" class="boxy"></div>
```

Comment: option 2 did not work... the result shows the URL below the dropdown, however, it doesn take to the respective page..